# Which is max filesize copy function allow in php

Tags: php, file, copy, filesize, php-7.2

I realized `copy` function can't copy files (from A to B) with too much size.

```
copy(SOURCE, DESTINATION);
```

My question is: there is any constant/function which can tell me which is the max filesize `copy` function can copy ?

I need that because I realized I can't copy too big files.

**New info:**

If file is too big is trying for while to copy it and after that PHP returns a 503. There is no error in error_log.

**New info:**

I do that on Linux, source and destination are both on the same host. There is enough space on this remote host I use.

I am interested of a constant/function which can tell me dinamically (for any host/device) which is the max size `copy` function can read and write in destination.

Comment: How much is "_too much size_"? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @kerbholz no. I don't get any error. It just can't copy it. And returns 503 after a while of trying to copy it.

Comment: But what file sizes are we talking about? 10MB? 1GB? 1TB? What OS? Are the source/destination on the local drive? Are they the same drive? Are you copying to/from different drives? Are they network drive(s)? Is their enough free space on the destination? What's the file systems, like Ext? Fat32? NTFS? Other? Have you tried copy the file using the OS? Does that work? Please edit your question to include a detailed description of your setup including any debugging you've done.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I just did that. Please check it out.

Comment: So.. what sizes are we talking about (third time it's asked)? And have you tried copy it using the OS, like `cp x y` in the console? Does that work?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson it's about a remote host. I don't have access on console. I want to make an if() before use copy to check if copy function will can copy the file (in the same device, Linux OS).